# Iron absorption and oxidative stress

Tags: human-biology, hematology, nutrition

Fe2+ is more bioavailable than Fe3+, so it's absorbed more quickly. I read that, for this reason, Fe2+ doesn't give enough time to the organism to bind it to a protein then it stays longer in a damaging free form in blood.

So if we consider 2 persons absorbing (in blood) the same amount of iron via Fe3+ for one and Fe2+ for the other, will Fe2+ generate more oxidative stress?

In response to David:

> The bioavailability of a drug product is known as the rate and extent
> of its absorption.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK557405/

So, high bioavailability means high rate of absorption which means that, for a given duration, a higher amount is absorbed, so it's absorbed more quickly.

By protein I meant ferritin or transferrin.

> Ferritin preserves iron in a safe state; thus, it is a direct defense
> molecule against redox-active iron.
>
> Non-transferrin bound iron is a candidate for the redox-active iron in
> extracellular space.
>
> When a large amount of iron enters cells and overflows the capacity of
> iron binding proteins, the iron behaves as a redox-active iron in the
> cell.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9324531/

If iron can overflow the capacity of iron binding proteins, it means that it's about time since a slower absorption could help to prevent this overflow. As you can see, it's not a nonsense.

So, is Fe2+ more likely to cause such an overflow and thus more oxidative stress?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please either provide a link or quote the exact text and context of what you have read. That way we can check whether the author is correct and whether your understanding is correct. Statements such as "it's absorbed more quickly because it's more bioavailable" and "Doesn't give the organism time to bind the protein" are scientifically ambiguous at best and meaningless at worst. Which protein is "a protein", and could you check this is about affinity rather than the nonsensical "time to bind"? Are you just asking whether free ferrous ions cause more oxidative stress?

Comment: that info seems readily available online, did you check this list of findings: https://www.google.com/search?q=oxidative+stress+fe2+fe3&oq=oxidative+stress+fe2+fe3&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l3.7224j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Most of the studies I found were about Fe2+ causing oxidative stress, and since Fe3+ has to be reduced to Fe2+ to be absorbed, Fe3+ may also cause oxidative stress. I didn't find any study comparing Fe2+ and Fe3+ intakes to confirm that Fe2+ generates more oxidative stress.

Comment: 1. Please don't refer to me in your question. Edit it instead. 2. If you respond to a comment of mine, you need to leave a comment addressed to @david so I am alerted to it. (I don't have to do this to you as the poster or answerer always gets notified of comments.) Iron is a vital mineral not a drug, and your statements about bioavailability would seem to mean that ingested Fe2+ is taken up by cells less well than Fe3+.The question is why? Is it possible that it might be because transferrin only binds Fe3+. Check if/how Fe2+ can be taken up into cells and edit the start of your Q accordingly.

Comment: I know little about iron metabolism but I am an experienced biochemist/molecular biologist. I may be able to help you if you do the work to research your question in molecular and cellular terms. I have glanced very briefly at the literature and it would appear that bioavailability basically means absorption into the circulation. However it is absorption into cells that would appear of interest as that's where oxidative stress occurs. For Fe3+ this requires transferrin, interacting with receptors on the cell. If Fe2+ is not taken up the question is invalid. Is there a mechanism for this?